# Using Visual Database Creation Systems Over Traditional Database Creation Methods

Tags: sql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm creating an offline search-engine like application that's also like a dictionary, and I thought I'd use an SQL database. However, I only know database basics (a few SQL commands, how databases and relationships are supposed to work) but wouldn't like to spend a lot of time studying about them.

Is it a good idea for me to just use a visual database creation system (I was thinking MySQL Workbench), or should I learn more about databases first? And if so, how much is enough to create one of the application?

This is my first time developing software, so I am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good for you

Comment: Creating my database from scratch in SQL? Do you have any suggestions as to how much time I should spend? Thanks!

Comment: From 4 min to a few years. You can not expect to get concrete answers to general abstract questions

Comment: Ok, well thank you. I guess I have to start working on that now.